# Combine records based on unique account number

Tags: sql, recursion, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with 30,000+ records following the below format.

```
PK, AccountNo, OwnerFname, OwnerLname
1   1          John        Smith
2   1          Julie       Smith
3   2          Eric        Doe
4   2          Sara        Doe
5   3          Bill        Johnson
6   4          Don         Carlson
7   4          Donna       Carlson
```

I need to create an query that produces the following results.

```
AccountNo, OwnerFname, OwnerLname, Owner2Fname, Owner2Lname
1          John        Smith       Julie        Smith
2          Eric        Doe         Sara         Doe
3          Bill        Johnson
4          Don         Carlson     Donna        Carlson
```

Is this even possible? I believe I will need to use a recursive query but cant seem to get the combination right.

Comment: Why do you want to combine them in this way? Wouldn't it make the result harder, not easier, to work with (you don't even know how wide the data is)

Comment: Are there a maximum number of potential owners?  No more than 2?  Or is it unlimited (in which case, a dynamic query would be needed)?

Comment: The query is merging the rows so mailing labels can be printed without duplicates (1 per unit). The software has a rule that only 2 official owners can be assigned to a unit so it doesn't have to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is `PIVOT` your results.  SQL Server supports the `PIVOT` command, but I like the readability of using `MAX` with `CASE`.  Both options assume you know the number of potential columns though.  If not, you'll need to look into using Dynamic SQL.

Using Max/Case approach -- this uses a common table expression and `ROW_NUMBER` to pivot your results on:

```
with cte as (
  select row_number() over (partition by accountno order by pk) rn,
    accountno, ownerfname, ownerlname
  from yourtable
  )
select 
  accountno, 
  max(case when rn = 1 then ownerfname end) OwnerFname,
  max(case when rn = 1 then ownerlname end) OwnerLname,
  max(case when rn = 2 then ownerfname end) OwnerFname2,
  max(case when rn = 2 then ownerlname end) OwnerLname2
from cte
group by accountno
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bcda5/3)